# Cannot call FormApp.getUi() from bound Google Forms script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

As the title says, **I'm trying to get the UI of a Google Form from a script**, so that I can show an alert box to the user with some information.

This is the relevant part of the function:

```
function Foobar(){
    ...
    var ui = FormApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Foo", "bar", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

This code executes on the "On form submit" event trigger. Invariably, a few seconds later I get an email containing this error:

```
Cannot call FormApp.getUi() from this context.
```

Now, from [my understanding](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), bound scripts (like this one, it was created from the form via Tools -> Script Editor) *should* have access to the ui of the form.

I already tried calling the same function from SpreadsheetApp, in case the form response automatically switched to the spreadsheet, but no dice. I also tried saving a (global) reference to the UI from a function called by the "On open" trigger, but that too failed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't possible in response to a form submission, you can't actually interact with the UI of a user-facing Google Form in "real time" at all.

At the documentation you linked, it states this limitation:

> (Note that in Google Forms, user-interface elements are visible only
>   to an editor who opens the form to modify it, not to a user who opens
>   the form to respond.)

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood what they meant by editor. Thanks a lot for pointing that out!